# Google-selected canonical is my original site rather than my multilingual site

Tags: seo, google-search-console, canonical-url, hreflang, trailing-slash

Google-selected canonical is my original site rather than my multilingual site!

I built a website `www.example.com`, then I made it a multilingual site, with an "en" at the end. (original website still exists!)

Google didn't index my multilingual website: domain end with en or with en/。 And when I inspect this page `www.example.com/en` on Google Search Console, I find that Google-selected canonical is my original website `www.example.com`.

What should I deal with it? Add a canonical tag to my "en" page? Another question is what should I deal with `www.example.com/en` and `www.example.com/en/` pages, they are all not indexed by Google. GSC also shows a "Duplicate without user-selected canonical" error for these two pages, and both of them have referring pages on my website.

Both of `www.example.com/en` and `www.example.com/en/` pages have hreflang tags, but they don't have any canonical tags.

[image: hreflang tag]

[image: en-end page inspection on GSC][image: en/-end page inspection on GSC]

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the hreflang tags (and any canonical tags) used on both the versions?

Comment: already edited. These two versions(with / and without /) have the same herflang tags, however, both of them are lack of canonical tags.

Comment: Google doesn't use the language from '<html lang="en">`.   Its good to have it there, but Google always guesses the language based on the words used on the page and ignores your declared language from the html lang attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html lang` tag informs the user-agent about the current document. This tag doesn't define a relationship between different language versions.

`hreflang` tags are better because they inform Google of the alternate language versions of a crawled document (from any of the language versions).

For example, assume `example.com` is the German version (the default one). Also, let us assume `example.com/en/` is the English version. Let there be a page `/xyz`

Now your hreflang tags in both German and English versions will look like this:

```
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en"
       href="https://example.com/en/xyz" />
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de"
       href="https://example.com/xyz" />
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default"
       href="https://example.com/xyz" />
```

When Google crawls `https://example.com/xyz` it will know the corresponding English version is `https://example.com/en/xyz` and vice-versa. Thus Google will not consider them duplicates.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions#html

Regarding trailing slash issue for `example.com/en`, you can add a canonical tag that points to the URL with the trailing slash - `example.com/en/`.

Comment: Thanks Kannan. I'm wondering that, actually, the content in my English version is totally different from the default one. However, in Google webmaster, Google canonical URL in my English version is still the default one. Does `hreflang` tag can fix it?

Comment: Provided the content is different, hreflang should fix it. However, there have been several discussions in Google support forums that sometimes Search Console may display an error but correct language pages for appropriate users will still show in search results due to hreflang tags. https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/5720658/multi-regional-domains-with-same-content-google-ignores-canonical-tag?hl=en 
After implementation give Google some time. If error persists, you can do a location based testing to find if hreflang works to display correct results despite search console errors.

Comment: Thanks Kannan! I want to cast a vote for your answer, but my account now under 15 reputations. I'm going to fix it according to your suggestion. thank you!